# php PDO connection does work and mysqli connection to DB doesn't

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, database-connection

In few words, this works:

```
<?PHP

include 'cal_config.php';

$dbms = 'mysql';
$dsn = "$dbms:host=$_dbIp;dbname=$_dbDbase";
$cn=new PDO($dsn, $_dbUte, $_dbPass);
$cn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = $cn->prepare("SELECT * FROM notifiche");
$query->execute();
$res = $query->fetchAll();

print_r($res);
?>
```

The above PDO connection works but using mysqli:

```
<?PHP
$core = mysqli_connect($_dbIp,$_dbUte,$_dbPass,$_dbDbase) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error());
?>
```

dies with "Connection refused".

Can someone explain me why? Thanks in advance

**EDIT: SOLVED**

My bad, the old apache server was outside my new local network and every php script containing mysqli query pointed to the public ip address of my network. The new apache server is under my new local network but the old scripts were pointing to the public ip address of mysql server and not to the new local address. I hope you understand what i mean:

- old apache server outside local network ------> public ip address of mysql server inside local network **working**
- new apache server inside local network -------> local ip address of mysql server inside local network **working** (the mistake was i was using public ip address of mysql server even if both server were in local)

Hope it's clear

Comment: I started this project month ago. At start i was using mysqli then i discovered PDO and started using it with pleasure. But now i have old scripts that still use mysqli. With first server i was using, both method worked but now i changed server and only PDO is working

Comment: I think it's something related to server configuration but cannot figure what's the problem

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your php.ini ?

Comment: Can it be a firewall problem? maybe i need to redirect that 3306 port?

Comment: depends is port 3306 already in use?

Comment: I don't think that port 3306 is already in use. Does PDO use that port? if Yes, PDO works with that port. If not then i need to check if it's in use by something else even if i don't think so